# How can I set property of subclass to a type which is a subclass of the property's type in the parent class?

Tags: typescript, class, types, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have the class `Element`

```
export class Element {
  public id: string;
  public name: string;
  public node: HTMLElement; // All element classes are subclasses from this.

  constructor(id: string, name: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

And I want to create a Slider class, by extending Element.

```
export class Slider extends Element {
  public min: number;
  public max: number;
  public value: number;
  public step: number;

  constructor(id: string, name: string, min: number, max: number, value: number, step: number) {
    super(id, name);
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
    this.value = value;
    this.step = step;
    this.node = document.createElement("input"); // This should be of type HTMLInputElement
    this.node.id = id;
    this.node.type = "range";
  }
}
```

I am getting an error here:
`Property 'type' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.`

Didn't `this.node` become of type `HTMLInputElement` when doing `createElement("input")`?

**How can I make `this.node` be of type `HTMLInputElement` in the `Slider` class?**

Comment: No, assigning a value to a non-union typed property doesn't narrow the apparent type of the property.  Instead you can just explicitly narrow the type of the property for that subclass, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mZQ39N).  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I would slightly change the Element class like:

```js
    export class Element<TElement extends HTMLElement = HTMLElement> {
      public id: string;
      public name: string;
      public node: TElement; // All element classes are subclasses from this.
    
      constructor(id: string, name: string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
      }
    }
```

Now the Slider Class :

```js
    export class Slider extends Element<HTMLInputElement> {
      public min: number;
      public max: number;
      public value: number;
      public step: number;
    
      constructor(id: string, name: string, min: number, max: number, value: number, step: number) {
        super(id, name);
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        this.value = value;
        this.step = step;
        this.node = document.createElement("input");
        this.node.id = id;
        this.node.type = "range";
      }
    }
```